# Should Moderator Election rules be changed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, badges, election

If I have **ALL** of the required badges to be a moderator, save `Yearling`.

Why should that one badge disqualify anyone?

Some people have been active users for *almost* a year.

I see no reason why not having one of the six badges (especially one that has nothing to do with the quality of their work) should disqualify anyone as a moderator.

Can we change the rules so that `Yearling` is not required, but maybe is a plus when getting into the primaries?

*We Don't Need No Stinkin' Badges!*

Comment: lol. Wow **HARSH** ^_^

Comment: @Rocket no freakin idea. but my nomination was removed because i did not have one stinkin badge...

Comment: There's required badges?  I can understand Yearling, but there are others?

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama: Not really the attitude from someone who wants to be a moderator is it? Nominations have only just opened so I would imagine the requirements may change based on feedback. (It already has as the Pundit badge was a requirement but has now been removed)

Comment: @Barry i updated the question's question to sound less pompous

Comment: Ranting about it probably won’t make it change for this election, and it definitely does’t put you in a better light for the job… but maybe that’s just me.

Comment: @Barry: Shouldn't this count as "feedback"?

Comment: @poke ha, i see that now ^_^ but its a little late now.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I should have said "constructive feedback" rather than just feedback.

Comment: @Barry: Fair enough.

Comment: I find it incredible that this legitimate question has been downvoted so much. @AManAPlanACanalPanama was simply curious as to ***why*** `Yearling` was a necessary badge, and he's being punished for it.

Comment: @zzzzBov thanks ^_^ although it comes with the territory. sometimes you get a bad bout and people can't help but to follow in other's footsteps

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama - at the rate you're going you'll be banned from meta for this post :) and all its downvotes lol.

Comment: @JonH it has happened before ^_^. and I have come back from it :-D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some review, we have decided to revoke the requirement for the Yearling badge (much like we did with Pundit).

Comment: I noticed that my revoked nomination is back, but I cannot comment on it, why is that?

Comment: @AMan I'll get someone to look into that. We had the same happen on Gaming earlier.

Comment: Can you please let me know when that is fixed? it is quite frustrating.... :-(

Comment: Good move Grace!

Comment: This is really a terrible idea.  Is there such a dearth of qualified candidates that have been around a year that we need to expand the pool that much more?  Being around a year indicates commitment to the site.

Answer (score 28):

My guess is that they want people who have been active on SO for at least a year. It won't be long before another election is run (at most a year). If you are serious about participating wait until you actually meet the requirements.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is simply dedication.

As a moderator you're given enhanced privileges, and we'd like to be certain that you're going to use them actively and fairly.

If you haven't been committed to SO for at least a year, how do we know that you're going to stick around once you've become a moderator?

Comment: Ha. It should be at least half a year. not a year. I have been commited if you see anyone's rep history who has previously been nominated then removed that they are fully active.

Comment: Also as a side point, alot of the people who get the yearling badges are users who have not been on in a while and have very low rep.

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama, I recently achieved the Yearling badge, but after observing last years election, I fully understand that I'm not qualified to be a moderator. I am missing a couple badges that are in the list as required, but more importantly, I *know* i'm not dedicated enough to be a moderator. Despite having some of the higher-level privileges, I rarely if ever use them.