# Automatically enforce badge requirements for moderator candidates

Tags: feature-request, moderation, nominations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the nomination page ask me to nominate myself when I'm not eligible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111261/why-does-the-nomination-page-ask-me-to-nominate-myself-when-im-not-eligible)

I've seen a few users on Stack Overflow who have chosen to nominate themselves for Moderator status. However, some of them do not meet the badge requirements to become a Moderator.

I would like to propose enforcing badge requirements automatically as a prerequisite for applying as candidate, thus users need not worry if candidates meet the requirements or not.

A Donald Trump check, if you will.

Comment: The badge requirements is currently only for this Stack Overflow election. If it gets rolled out to other elections then I would expect it to be automatic. At the moment manual checks are probably sufficient.

Comment: You mean to send a bunch of people down for a holiday and report back how great the mai tais are?

Comment: Those badge requirements suck.

Comment: Last I checked, no ineligible nominations were present. (There are currently 10 candidates as I post this.)

Comment: @Pekka: I can kinda see the point...they require that you have been (1) voting, (2) editing, (3) flagging, and (4) participating in meta. That is that you've been putting some time and effort into maintaining and improving the site. Obviously they would not be good for a small site, but it's not like Stack Overflow has a dearth of qualified users. Ah...and apparently there was a requirement--now dropped--that you'd been around for a year now. Glad to see that one gone as the others are better.