# Election idea regarding Yearling requirement

Tags: discussion, election

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should Moderator Election rules be changed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111256/should-moderator-election-rules-be-changed)

Seeing that the rules for election have changed from last time I respect that a potential moderator needs to show dedication and experience among other things...

I am not so sure that Yearling is the right badge for that - since Yearling just needs to be there 1 year and earn at least 200 rep...

A Fanatic OTOH needs to be there at least 100 days in a row - that shows lots of dedication IMO...

I would like to suggest extending the Yearling requirement to be `(Yearling OR (Fanatic AND rep > 10k))`...

Is that a viable idea ?

Comment: We've simply removed the Yearling requirement.

Comment: ok - in that case my post has no use :-)

Comment: @GraceNote: Aw... and that was one of the badges I *did* have.

Comment: @Grace Note So is Yearling not existing anymore?