# Comment-link not appearing for some of the election nominations

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, election

I was just browsing through the nomination list and noticed that the “add comment” link does not appear for every candidate. I have over 10k reputation so I guess that shouldn’t be an issue, and overall the selection of which candidates I cannot comment on seems rather random.

I first thought it was because of the age of the nomination, but just now a new nomination appeared and I could comment on it. Then I thought that I maybe need more reputation than the candidate, but apart from the fact that this makes no sense at all, it is not the case for one nomination. Also some of those where I cannot comment already do have comments.

Is this a bug, or is there actually a system behind this?

Comment: It's because their nominations have been reinstated after the [badge requirements changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111256/should-moderator-election-rules-be-changed/111290#111290). No idea when (or indeed whether) this will be sorted.

Comment: See @GraceNote's answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111256/should-moderator-election-rules-be-changed/111290#111290

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug related to the fact that if a user withdraws but then... un-withdraws? Double withdraws by withdrawing the withdrawal? Draws?

Whatever it is, it causes an issue in which the post cannot be commented on. If my memory is correct, it's because withdrawing locks the post but the reverse action does not unlock it automatically.

This is now fixed.

Comment: haha. well thats a little confusing :-P

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing this up; good that I was not alone :D

Comment: @poke -- it seems that this has been fixed (at least on stack overflow)

Comment: It's not fixed entirely. For example you can't comment on Adam's nomination.

Comment: @Code Fixed that now.