# Is this really the appropriate response to a "helpful" flag?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, moderation, helpful-flags

This is what I just got to a flag that I put on an [old dumb question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111256/155556)

I wrote:

> Can this please be deleted? It is old and irrelevant. Thank you.

And it would have been fine if it was just rejected and I would have need none the wiser...

But what I got was worse:
I saw **`helpful`**, ok cool. Then the mod's comment `Just kidding - NO.`

You cannot be serious?!

Should moderators really be responding to people like that?

---

Pictorial evidence:
[image]

Comment: Well, it made me laugh....

Comment: I can't figure out exactly where the relevant information is in your photo. Perhaps you could highlight it in some way? ;)

Comment: Funny @Bart... very funny...

Comment: @AndrewBarber this question does not deserve any freehand circles.

Comment: What's wrong with the response? I know we're supposed to hate fun, but ... come on.

Comment: @Yannis it is mean and uncalled for and not what a moderator should be doing or representing.

Comment: @amanaP for a new user and his/her first couple of flags, I would absolutely agree. But you've been here for a while now. You know how this thing works. You know them, they know you. Can you not try to see the humorous side here?

Comment: No I really cannot @Bart ...

Comment: @gnat -- the flag **was not** declined! That is the whole issue, if it **was** declined then I would have no question.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA do you mean that helpful flags can have messages now?

Comment: Apparently @gnat

Comment: Seems so @gnat. Otherwise there would have been a red declined + message.

Comment: That's not actually something moderators can do.

Comment: We can only post a message on a flag if we decline it.  I'm trying to raise a community manager to get some clarification on what happened.

Comment: Wow... that is very weird @BilltheLizard Keep us updated :-D

Comment: @BilltheLizard There's no UI for leaving a message if helpful, but I wonder if the POST action has a parameter for a message...

Comment: @GeorgeStocker So a mod might have _hacked_ the system?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA or a dev did it lol

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Someone who has higher access than you or I left the message.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I saw that.  I'm just wondering if perhaps that person used their JavaScript-fu and knowledge of the codebase to create a script that allows them to leave messages on `helpful`.  I've seen their work on other JavaScript-y things, so they definitely have the technical knowhow.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker That's a possibility. I thought they might just have database access.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Seems like a pain (unless they have better tooling around it) to have to do to just mess with a user.

Comment: Hence the whole question here :-D @GeorgeStocker

Comment: or what if there is  malware on the server...!? >;] i hear its a popular trend right now

Comment: Strictly-speaking, any moderator can leave a message along with Helpful, @Bill - there's just no UI for it. I've been playing with the notion for a while (since this is [a rather popular feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160338/allow-moderators-to-reply-to-a-flag)) to see where the potential uses / pitfalls lie - here's one of them.

Comment: @Shog9 Well, now you're going to have a couple of dozen moderators trying to figure this out. :)

Comment: ABOUT TIME! @Bill ;-)

Comment: @BilltheLizard So what you're saying is that we should go on a flagging binge to give you some flags to test with?

Comment: @Servy Yes, Bill would certainly love for you to go on a flagging binge on SO.

Comment: @Servy We have 902 in the queue at the moment. I'll let you know if we run out.  :)

Comment: related: [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/552/the-i-get-it-reputation-problem)

Answer (score 26):

You've flagged this same question *four times* now. The last time you flagged it, I wrote,

> Declined: As a completed feature-request, it's part of the history of the evolution of SO's election system

Note that your question doesn't stand alone - it's referenced in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111524/add-yearling-back-to-the-requirements-for-moderator) asking that the Yearling requirement be added back. It's hardly implausible that this request will come up again (it's a rather appealing requirement) - indeed, I can't be sure these posts haven't been referenced on other sites on the network since they were written!

I assume you *know* all of this, since you're not *new* here and you're pretty familiar with how the system works. And yet you keep asking for it to be deleted anyway.

So again, for what I *sincerely* hope is the last time,

## NO.

Comment: The flag was marked as **helpful** 3 out of the 4 times with no action taken. If you were the one to decline my latest flag, this was not the way to do wit, and not the way that a moderator should act or respond to anything **regardless** of how long ***any*** user has been a part of a site.

Comment: Action was taken for all three "helpful" flags, @amana: the first resulted in the question being closed, the second in it being reopened, and the last in the composition of an attention-getting dismissal reason since you didn't seem to read the one attached to the "declined" reason. Yes, I could've - and probably should've - been a bit more polite about it, but... Really, you *do* know better by now. After 2+ years of active participation, I shouldn't have to hold your hand and explain how Meta works. I'm sorry for offending you with the message but *please* don't keep flagging the same posts.

Comment: @Shog9: I'm still interested in knowing how you've marked a flag helpful and provided a message at the same time :o

Answer (score 12):

That question was [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), it will not be removed even if you want it to.

### Why wouldn't it be removed?

- Because it was a completed feature, it serves as a signpost, and as history and followup for everyone, including devs.
- Even though it was downvoted, people put their time and effort into writing useful answers and suggestions.

### Was the response appropriate?

Probably not. I wouldn't have exploded over it though.

First (real) rule of the internet: Do not take things personally over the internet.

Comment: Not to mention all the people who'd spent time writing answers

Comment: Deletions of content more than a few months old don't affect Rep, IIRC. Also, he's not really complaining about the flag being denied, but rather the way the mod behaved.

Comment: @Madara I would end up **losing** rep if that question was deleted. Also this whole thing would have been no problem if the flag was just **declined** but it was handled very wrong.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Hence, I've added to my answer, the flag was probably not handled appropriately, someone wanted to have a little fun, but it ended up as being interpreted as abusive/harassing/annoying/trolling/whatever. Again, I wouldn't have exploded over it. But the choice is yours.

Comment: This whole thing might be a [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202983/is-this-really-the-appropriate-response-to-a-helpful-flag/202987?noredirect=1#comment646141_202983)